# Is it possible to globalize an instance which has been declared in a Class?

Tags: php, class, architecture, global

Is it possible to globalize an instance which has been declared in a Class?

For example:

```
<?php
   class Application
   {
      public $ioClass       = new Class();
      public $ioGlobalClass = new GlobalClass();

      public function __construct()
      {
          // constructor
      }
   }

   class Class 
   {
      public function __construct()
      {
          // constructor
      }

      public function doSomething()
      {
          // is this possible?
          global $ioGlobalClass;

          echo $ioGlobalClass->helloWorld();
      }
    }
 ?>
```

So can I do **global $ioGlobalClass;** in this example above?

Comment: Why would you even want to? Stay well clear of globals and singletons. There are almost always better ways of handling both and using them will almost certainly get you into trouble later on...

Comment: Its just a question if its possible. Next to that I have tried it with a non-global/non-singleton solution which caust a train wreck pattern..

Comment: @liquorvicar Singletons aren't inherently evil - there's a time and a place for them (ideal for session management classes for instance) - but they can lead you getting lazy... if you spot lots of Class::getInstance() calls throughout the app you know you're doing it wrong :)

Comment: I think the only way it might be possible would be to reference it through a global instantiation of your Application object... `$oApp = new Application(); $ioGlobalClass = $oApp->ioGlobalClass;` ... then that would be accessible as `global $ioGlobalClass` within `Class`; though that seems like bad idea to me.

Comment: @CD001 I didn't say Singletons were inherently evil!

Comment: @pascalvgemert Maybe edit your post with details about what the intention of your classes is. The *only* time you really need a Singleton is when having more than one instance of a class would seriously break things. Other forms of needing helper classes/services (I/O classes, DB access etc) can often be dealt with by some form of dependency injection/service locator pattern.

Comment: @CD001 ok clear! Thanks for the answer I was looking for, indeed thats not what I want, so I going to check out some other options.

Comment: @liquorvicar dependency injection is the solutions I hear the most, but how can I prevent a train-wreck pattern with lots of classes within classes within classes.. (mhh, maybe an example would explain more.. I'll try to give you one tomorrow if possible) Thanks for you help so far!

Comment: @pascalvgemert Here's a good place to start: http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: @liquorvicar thanks I will check it out! Quick responses btw ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect not if it hasn't been instantiated anywhere. You might have more luck with a singleton:

```
public static $ioGlobalClass = new GlobalClass()
```

then:

```
Application::$ioGlobalClass->helloWorld();
```

Comment: This is a static I believe? And in my example above it has been instantiated: 
`public $ioGlobalClass = new GlobalClass();`

Comment: @pascalvgemert: All global variables are static.

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can:

```
<?php
require_once('global_class.php');

class Application
{
  public $ioGlobalClass;

  public function __construct()
  {
      global $ioGlobalClass;
      $this->ioGlobalClass = $ioGlobalClass;          
  }
  ...
```

And in `global_class.php` you just write:

```
<?php
global $ioGlobalClass;
$ioGlobalClass = new GlobalClass();
```